# weak solution is classical solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, weak-derivatives

given  there exists an $u \in C^2(\Omega) \cap C(\Omega)$ such that $$0=\int_\Omega \nabla u \nabla v - fv ~dx,~ \forall v \in C^\infty_0(\Omega) $$

show that $u$ also solves pointwise

$$-\Delta u =f,~on~ \Omega$$
with zero boundary conditons.

I have to show that $u$ is twice continuous differentiable and continuous on the closure of $\Omega$.
My idea is just to integrate (parital)
$$\int_\Omega \nabla u \nabla v~ dx=-\int_\Omega v \Delta u~dx$$ 
and 
$$0=-\int_\Omega v (\Delta u-f)~dx~\forall v \in C^\infty_0(\Omega)$$
therefore $$\Delta u-f=0$$ almost everywhere.
but now I stuck, can someone help? I think I can't use any sobolev embeddings because I dont know in which space $f$ lies.

Comment: I think you forgot to mention that $f$ is in $L^2(\Omega)$ which is natural.

Comment: its not explicitly mentioned, but I think that the assumption that the weak problem has an "classical" solution implies some regularity on $f$.

Comment: indeed and for the $\int_\Omega fvdx$ to be well defined we need $f$ to be in $L^2(\Omega)$

Comment: Is you problem getting from "almost everywhere" to "everywhere"? Remember $u$ is twice continuously differentiable, so $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach to go from weak form to the strong form of equation is to use the distributions notations,

We already have $v\in\mathcal{D(\Omega)}=C_0^\infty(\Omega)$, and we can observe easily that $u$ defines a distribution because it is a $C^2(\Omega)\cap C^1(\Omega)$.

So the integrals can be written as duality crochets as follows,
$$ \left<  \nabla u,\nabla v\right>_{D'(\Omega),D(\Omega)}=\left<   f, v\right>_{D'(\Omega),D(\Omega)}$$
Now, we can use the derivation of the distribution to get the Laplacien operator

$$\left<  \nabla u,\nabla v\right>_{D'(\Omega),D(\Omega)}=-\left<  \Delta u,v\right>_{D'(\Omega),D(\Omega)} $$
Hence, we obtain $$ -\Delta u=f$$
Given that $f\in L^2(\Omega)$, then we have our result
$$-\Delta u=f\quad \mbox{on } \Omega $$